# NG Live Dev Server config

Tags: angular-cli

I have a CLI project that has multiple apps, when I run build my dist folder looks like

dist/appone

dist/apptwo

Although these are two distinct apps they will be running on the server under a single host like

www.mydomain.com/appone

www.mydomain.com/apptwo

I need to have some interop between the two apps via browser local storage but on my local machine each app has to run on a different port so appone cannot access the values created by app two.

Is it possible to configure the local dev server that comes with the CLI to start up and have it's root point to dist so that it is more like an actual webserver?

localhost:4200/appone

localhost:4200/apptwo

running at the same time so I can test the interop?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no based on research. Need a different local web server like apache for this.